# Repeating a process 1000 times and creating a plot

Tags: r, repeat, statistics-bootstrap

Let's start with some data:

```
df <- rnorm(30)
```

I want to randomly sample 1000 times `df` obtaining each time 5 numbers without repetition and calculate its coefficient of variation (`cv`):

```
sample_df <- sample(df, 5, replace = F) 
cv <- (sd(sample_df) / mean(sample_df)) * 100
```

So now. I would like to repeat 1000 times the two last lines of code, so I would get 1000 coefficients. How can I do it?

Later on, I would like to merge all of the coefficients and draw an histogram or a density plot.

Comment: Just use `replicate` to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place the codes inside a brace and use `replicate`

```
n <- 1000
out <- replicate(n, {sample_df <- sample(df, 5, replace = FALSE)
               sd(sample_df)/mean(sample_df) * 100})
hist(out)
```

EDIT: Based on @Ben Bolker's comments

Comment: ... and assign the results to a variable (`r <- replicate(...)`), then use `hist(r)` ...